# How would i draw a portion of a path on top of an already existing path

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

```
let pathFeatures = getFlightPath(
    shipment.from.lnglat,
    shipment.to.lnglat
).features;

let flightPath = mapSelection
    .selectAll(`.flight-path${i}`)
    .data(pathFeatures)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", `flight-path flight-path${i}`)
    .attr("d", path as any);
```

using the svg path above how would i construct a second path to place on top that renders only a portion say `(0.4 * totalLength)` or 40% and have it transition to 100% after a duration.

Basically the underlying path will have a style of a `stroke-dasharray` (dotted path) that will indicate the path yet to have traveled, where i want an overlaying path that will be solid indicating the path already traveled. Then i will want to transition that solid path to 100% of its length after a duration.

How will i go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its amazing how you spend 3 hours failing to solve a problem the day before,then get some decent rest, and you're able to solve it within the first half hour of the next working day.

Take breaks people, sometimes the problem can be easily solved with a clear fresh mind.

```
let totalLength = flightPath.node().getTotalLength();
let lengthTraveled = flightPath.node().getTotalLength() * shipment.progress;
let lengthToBeTraveled = flightPath.node().getTotalLength() - lengthTraveled;

mapSelection
                .selectAll(`flight-traveled${i}`)
                .data(pathFeatures)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("class", `flight-traveled flight-traveled${i}`)
                .attr(
                    "stroke-dasharray",
                    `${lengthTraveled} ${lengthToBeTraveled}`
                )
                .transition()
                .duration(msRemaining)
                .ease(easeLinear)
                .attr("stroke-dasharray", `${totalLength} 0`)
                .attr("d", path as any);
```